# Check user's age with laravel validation rules

Tags: validation, laravel, model

How can I check the age of a user upon registration? I want to set the minimum age to be 13 years old. I ask for the user's date of birth and when I validate the other credentials, I want to check that they are in fact 13+.

An excerpt from my User model looks like this:

```
$rules = [
            'name'                  => 'required|alpha|min:1',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'dob'                   => 'required|date'
         ];
```

How can I check that the date entered is 13 years ago or more?

I have seen that I can use the `before:yyy-mm-dd` rule from the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-before), like so:

```
$rules = [
            'name'                  => 'required|alpha|min:1',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'dob'                   => 'required|date|before:2001-04-15'
         ];
```

1. How do I calculate the value?
2. How do I use that value within the rules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RMcLeod answer is OK, but I'd suggest you extracting this as a custom rule:

```
Validator::extend('olderThan', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $minAge = ( ! empty($parameters)) ? (int) $parameters[0] : 13;
    return (new DateTime)->diff(new DateTime($value))->y >= $minAge;

    // or the same using Carbon:
    // return Carbon\Carbon::now()->diff(new Carbon\Carbon($value))->y >= $minAge;
});
```

This way you can use the rule for any age you like:

```
$rules = ['dob' => 'olderThan']; // checks for 13 years as a default age
$rules = ['dob' => 'olderThan:15']; // checks for 15 years etc
```

Comment: Thank you, I will consider this later as it is currently working with @RMcLeod's answer and I only want to check that they are 13.

Comment: where does the Validation extension go?

Comment: Wherever you want to put it, add file with your custom extensions, append it to routes, global etc. It's totally up to you and how you organize your code. I would definitely go with something like `app/YourFolder/Validation/rules.php

Comment: Great answer by the way, just a note that I'm having a problem when the dob date is bigger than today date, the validation will return true since there is no negative date result using the diff() function. For those who have this problem, add another rules to dob `before:today`, then everything works prefectly.

Answer (score 57):

A simple way to check that the date is greater(older) than N years is to set the `before` rule to *minus N* years.

```
$rules = [
    'dob' => 'required|date|before:-13 years',
]
```

Comment: This is amazing. I find it more valuable than any other answers.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Carbon which comes with laravel

```
$dt = new Carbon\Carbon();
$before = $dt->subYears(13)->format('Y-m-d');

$rules = [
    ...
    'dob' => 'required|date|before:' . $before
];
```

Comment: Where do I put this? On the model?

Comment: Where ever you are doing your validation, basically you determine the date 13 years ago using Carbon and then use that to create your rules array

Answer (score 13):

This is a bit old, but I want to share the way I do it.

```
 public function rules()
{
    return 
    [
        ...
        'age' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:'.\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYears(18)->format('Y-m-d'),
        ...
    ];
}
```

Using `before` is nice but it's a bit ugly for the end user, because if today it's his birthday, he won't be able to pass. With `before_or_equal` you get the perfect behaviour. A way to improve this would be checking the timezone with Carbon if you target a worldwide audience.

Comment: Thanks but that validation rule was only introduced in Laravel 5.4 and when I asked the question Laravel 4 was the latest version. But yes, today that would work great!

Answer (score 1):

I have Implement This & Successfully Work
You Can Use

> before:'.now()->subYears(18)->toDateString()

```
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                
                'birthdate' => 'required|date|before:'.now()->subYears(18)->toDateString(),
                
            ], [
                'birthdate.before' => trans('18 year validation'),                
            ]);
```