# Run task before validation in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, date, laravel

Okay, so I have a form where it asks the user for:-

- The day on which they were born (0-31, etc.)
- The month in which they were born (January-December)
- The year in which they were born

I then validate this with:

```
$rules = array(
    '???'   => 'required:date'
);
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

But I have no idea where/what I can do to put the date, month, year into something that I can put into my validation, whether it be on the view or in the validation process.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Would you not be best validating each input individually to produce more usable error codes when things aren't right? Perhaps Input::get('date') as a range 1-31, Input::get('year') as a range 1920-2014, and Input::get('month') as either the name of the month or a range 1-12?

Comment: I'm not sure because I was planning to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-age-with-laravel-validation-rules#23082367 to validate the users age.

Comment: So you want to turn it all into a single date? Perhaps something with the inputs and the strtotime() function?

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by that?

Comment: If you want to use the linked validation rule your date needs to come in as a single field in a format that Laravel's date parser will be able to recognise (`dd-mm-yyyy`, `dd/mm/yy`, `yyyy-mm-dd`, etc.). If it comes in as three separate fields you need to turn them into a single field before they get near the validator. Something like this maybe: `$v = Validator::make(Input::only('name', 'email') + ['date' => Input::get('year').'-'.Input::get('month').'-'.Input::get('day'), $rules);`

Comment: That's great! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @TomDoyle sorry I don't get notifications on comments. expanded slightly and added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the linked validation rule your date needs to come in as a single field in a format that Laravel's date parser will be able to recognise (dd-mm-yyyy, dd/mm/yy, yyyy-mm-dd, etc.) - so your form should really contain a single text field called 'date' in this case.

If it comes in as three separate fields you need to turn them into a single field before they get near the validator. Something like this maybe:

```
$rules = [
    'name'  => ['required'],
    'email' => ['required', 'email'],
    'date'  => ['required', 'date'],
];

// transform date from three separate fields to yyyy-mm-dd
// TODO: ensure the things are zero-padded maybe?
$date = Input::get('year').'-'.Input::get('month').'-'.Input::get('day');

$v = Validator::make(
    Input::only('name', 'email') + ['date' => $date],
    $rules
);
```