# custom error message for age validation in a form.(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a form in which user must be of age 18 years or above.I have tried some methods but didn't worked.

in my controller:

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'birthday' => 'required|date|before:-18 years',
]);
```

in request.php:(searched over internet)

```
abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
    public function messages()
    {
        return [

            'birthday.before' => 'You must be 18 years old or above',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: hi there is your birthdate a datetime/date?

Comment: @NewbeeDev its a date

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules

Comment: @NewbeeDev not this method

Comment: You have your answer here: [check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules)

Comment: @Ferran i kno how to validate but how to show custom error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't clearly about your question.
If you want custom message of before validate, please go to resources/lang/en/validation.php and change it at

```
'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the age from the date, then validate it as a number.

or you can validate a date, which is 18 years before now

```
$dt = new Carbon\Carbon();
$before = $dt->subYears(18)->format('Y-m-d');

$rules = [
     'dob' => 'required|date|before:' . $before
];
```

or you can extend the validate and make custom one like in this answer : [Check user's age with laravel validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules)

Comment: sry didn't get you

Comment: here is a full example in how to show custom error message, i hope it will help https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

Hi to get your validation errors store your validator inside a variable 
then just use `$validator->errors()` to get its errors

```
$validator = Model::validate($request,[
    'birthday' => 'required|date|before:-18 years',
]);
$errors = $validator->errors();
echo "You error in birthday: ".$errors->get('birthday')[0];
```