# Validate Age Variable - Laravel RegisterController

Tags: laravel

I have added 3 fields to the Laravel OOB Registration Form, they are Birth Month, Day, and Year. I pass these fields to the validator function in the RegisterController and convert them to an age with Carbon:

```
$theAge = Carbon::createFromDate($data['birthyear'], $data['birthmonth'], $data['birthday'])->age;
```

This part works fine, I can pass the variable to a field in the table and see the correct age.

How do I add $theAge to my Validator?

```
return Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users|confirmed',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'city' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'state' => 'required|string|max:2',
        'zipcode' => 'required|string|max:10',
        'brand' => 'required',
        'opt_in' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
        'birthmonth' => 'required',
        'birthday' => 'required',
        'birthyear' => 'required',
    ]);
```

I have tried the following but it appears to be ignored on validation:

```
$theAge => 'bail|min:21'
```

I have looked into the [After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#after-validation-hook) but don't understand how to use it in my situation.

Comment: What's inside your `$data` variable, can you post that?

Comment: $data is an array of values from the form request. protected function validator(array $data)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the calculated value back in the `$data` before you call the validator like this:

```
$theAge = Carbon::createFromDate($data['birthyear'], $data['birthmonth'], $data['birthday'])->age;

$data['age'] = $theAge;

return Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users|confirmed',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
    'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'city' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'state' => 'required|string|max:2',
    'zipcode' => 'required|string|max:10',
    'brand' => 'required',
    'opt_in' => 'required',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    'birthmonth' => 'required',
    'birthday' => 'required',
    'birthyear' => 'required',
    'age' => 'min:21'
]);
```

Alternatively, you can let the user select their date of birth using date picker (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) like this:

```
<input name="birthday" type="date">
```

and in your validator, do this define the age check plus a custom error message:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    // ... snipped
    'birthday' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:' . Carbon::now()->subYears(21)->toDateString() 
], [
    'birthday.before_or_equal' => 'You must be at least 21 years old.'
]);
```

Comment: The [merge](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) method is useful in this case: `$request->merge(['age' => $theAge])`

Answer (score 2):

you can add the $theAge variable to the data array.

```
$data['age'] = Carbon::createFromDate($data['birthyear'], $data['birthmonth'], $data['birthday'])->age;
```