# How to validate date of birth and minimum age

Tags: laravel

I have a date of birth , and I will wish to do 2 things: 
1) When, the use enters a date of birth, tha date should be coherent...
For example, if I enter, 2030-10-10, I must have an error message because the date is not coherent. Idem, if I enter 1947-10-10.

2) Is it possible to set the minimum age to be 18 years old?

In my **model** I have this:

```
protected $fillable = ['name_mark', 'dateofbirth', 'date_register'];
protected $dates = ['dateofbirth', 'date_register'];
```

In my **Controller** I have this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'name_mark' => 'required|min:3',
                'dateofbirth' => 'required|date',
                'date_register' => 'required|date'

        ]);
        Mark::create($request->all());

        flashy('Valider');
        return redirect()->route('marks.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');

    }
```

I am yet novice, I thank you for your help and explanation.

Comment: Laravel is based on php. Try to search https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=php+subtract+2+dates this gives alot of result. the idea is take birthdate as date object and today date as date object, calculate the different, the the difference is more than 18 years, I have not downvote you.

Comment: There already an answer to your question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23084043/386868)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check user's age with laravel validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
before:'.\Carbon\Carbon::now().'|before:18 years ago|
```

Or:

```
before:'.Carbon::now().'|before:'.Carbon::now()->subYears(13).'
```

This works for me, hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

'dateofbirth' => 'required|date|after:' . $date,