# set a due date dynamic

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to set a due date (dynamic), the person can register if it is 17to 60 years old.

I have tried this:

```
'date_naissance' => 'required|date|after:1960|before:2003-01-01'
```

But, I have to change the values each years.It is possible to improve this?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check user's age with laravel validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```php
$year = (int)date("Y");
'date_naissance' => 
    'required|date|after:'.($year - 59).'|before:'.($year - 16).'-01-01'
```

Or a bit more precise:

```
'date_naissance' => 
    'required|date|after:'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-59 year')).'|before:'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-16 year'))
```

It should work also with this:

```
'date_naissance' => 
    'required|date|after:-59 year|before:-16 year'))
```

Comment: Thank you dparoli it's ok mercy

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make custom validation rule. Here is example how to do it: 
[LINK](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/custom-validation-rules-in-laravel-5-5-c6cb250f65df)

You will need to make method that takes person birth date and calculate his age. If age is greater then 17 it should return true.