# Validating a textbox as required if the age is less than 18 Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a form where the parent name and details are required is the date of birth provided is of a minor using Laravel 8. In simple PHP I can do it but how to do it Laravel.

Comment: Very simple. Do you know Laravel? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules

Comment: I want to have Name as required field if the age is less than 18 otherwise it is not required using laravel.

Comment: Create a class that extends `FormRequest` class: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#creating-form-requests
Then in the rules() function have the ['first_name' => ['required'], 'last_name' => ['required']]. For age validation use the link I provided earlier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check user's age with laravel validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081654/check-users-age-with-laravel-validation-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm giving you a Laravel validation example based on your questions -

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $validated_data = $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => ['required_if:age,<,18'],
        'age'  => ['numeric', 'integer']
    ]);
}
```